# Importing SQLite to MS-Access: Datatype mismatch between the columns

Tags: sqlite, ms-access

I imported a SQLite DB into MS-Access using ODBC and it was successful except for one column. One of the columns in SQLite DB was of 'Integer' datatype but it contained a string since datatypes are flexible in SQLite. But in the imported MS-Access DB, the column corresponding to that particular datatype is blank. I assume that the Access DB was expecting a integer datatype and not accepting a string. The following is the table structure:

CREATE TABLE test
(
    num INTEGER,
    name TEXT,
    script INTEGER NOT NULL
);

I have problem with the column 'script'. I am not allowed to change the datatype here so is there any solution that I can workout in Access?

Comment: What do you mean when you say that you are "not allowed to change the datatype here"? Are you saying that you cannot change the [script] field type in the Access table?

Comment: I am not allowed to change the datatype in SQLite DB for some internal reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a SQLite VIEW named "forimport" to CAST the troublesome column as TEXT

```sql
CREATE VIEW forimport AS SELECT num, name, CAST(script AS TEXT) AS script FROM test;
```

and then import the view (instead of the table) from SQLite into Access

[image: import.png]